# Find index of last matching occurrence

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've got array of `variables` and next variable which I want to add alphabetically. It goes A-Z and after that AA, AB, AC etc.. 
so in when next variable is `E` I want to add it at the end of letters with length=1, if next variable would be `AC` I'd add it at the end on letters with length=2 etc. I tried to do it with findIndex, but it returns the first occurrence, not the last one and `lastIndexOf` accepts value while in my case it should be the last element with given length.

```js
let variables = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'AA', 'AB'];
const nextVariable = 'E';
const idx = variables.findIndex(x => x.length === nextVariable.length);
variables.splice(idx, 0, nextVariable);
console.log(variables);

// should be ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'AA', 'AB']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just look for the first variable which is *longer* than the variable to insert, and if it doesn't exist (`findIndex` returns -1), add to the end of the array:

```js
let variables = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'AA', 'AB'];
let nextVariable = 'E';
let idx = variables.findIndex(x => x.length > nextVariable.length);
variables.splice(idx < 0 ? variables.length : idx, 0, nextVariable);
// should be ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'AA', 'AB']
console.log(variables);
nextVariable = 'AC';
idx = variables.findIndex(x => x.length > nextVariable.length);
variables.splice(idx < 0 ? variables.length : idx, 0, nextVariable);
// should be ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC']
console.log(variables);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom sort function and test the alphabetical order and length of each value.

```
function mySort(a, b) {
  if(a.length == b.length) {
    return a.localeCompare(b);
  } else {
    return a.length - b.length;
  }
}
```

The you can use this function to sort the array after a new value has been added:

`variables.sort(mySort);`

Comment: Change localCompare to localeCompare

Answer (score 1):

```js
let variables = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'AA', 'AB'];
const nextVariable = 'E';
variables[variables.length] = nextVariable
variables = variables.sort((x,y) => x.length<y.length ? -1 : x.length==y.length ? x.localeCompare(y) : 1)
console.log(variables);
```

Comment: it gives: [
  "AE",
  "BE",
  "CE",
  "DE",
  "AA",
  "AB"
]

Comment: I totally misunderstood the question, thanks for pointing out. I will fix it